# Shipment comment

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, shipment

I am trying to update a comment for an existing shipment, but I keep getting err mssg:

```
{"message": "Could not save the shipment comment."}
```

API and example I'm using are :

Method:POST

Request: {{base_url}}/rest/all/V1/shipment/1/comments

```
{
    "entity": {

      "parent_id": 0,

      "comment": "test_test",

      "is_visible_on_front": 1

    }
}
```

Is it even possible to update comment for shipment ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this API.

```
/rest/default/V1/shipment/{id}/comments
```

Here is the parameter that use into that.

```
{
"entity": {
      "is_customer_notified": 0,
      "parent_id": 0,
      "extension_attributes": { },
      "comment": "string",
      "is_visible_on_front": 0,
      "created_at": "string",
      "entity_id": 0
   }
}
```

For more details, you can look into this one :
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for your comment.

You just sent me example from:
https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.6-admin/tag/shipmentidcomments#operation/PostV1ShipmentIdComments

API I the same as mine, only diff is that instead of {id} I put 1, as example.
And for entity, I only used required fields.


That should be fine, but but some reason I cant update comment.

Comment: Pass all the parameter as mention with default values and try the code into default magento only. In custom website may be some other extension create issue like this.